# how to select first 30 lines of datagrid to excel template and balance to page two

Tags: c#, excel, datagrid

I have a datagrid on my visual studio with 40 items. On button click I want the first 30 items to display on my excel template and the balance to go to page two of template.

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\CedarData\masterquote.xlsx", misValue, false, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //int i = 1;
        //int j = 1;

        string datestr = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        //string colName = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
        string filename = @"C:\CedarData\CedarQuotes\Quote_" + txtName.Text.Replace(" ", "") + "_" + datestr + ".xls";
        string quote = txtName.Text.Replace(" ", "") + "_" + datestr;
        string salesman = txtEmail.Text.ToUpper();
        string customer = txtName.Text.ToUpper();

        // Storing Each row and column value to excel sheet   
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
           {

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                //string value3 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                if (j == 2 || j == 5)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 19, j + 1] = "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 19, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                } 
                xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C10", "E10").Value2 = salesman;
                xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C12", "E12").Value2 = customer;
                xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C12", "E12").Font.Bold = true;
                xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C12", "E12").Font.Bold = true;
                xlWorkSheet.get_Range("H12", "I12").Value2 = DateTime.Now;
                xlWorkSheet.get_Range("H10", "I10").Value2 = quote;

            }

        }   

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\quote.xls");
    }
```

Please help as this works but on line 31 it ovewrites the clauses on template. I want it must continue to page two.

Comment: Are you asking about how to place the first 30 lines of data on Worksheet 1 and then put the remaining 10 lines of data on Worksheet 2?  If that is the case, you'll need to either toggle xlWorkSheet to point to WorkSheet 2 or create a new variable for WorkSheet 2 and then add logic to know once the first 30 lines have been placed on the first and place the rest on the second.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly! - Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: My apologies. Im working on visual studio. I have form1 that has over 200 items on a datagridview. On selection these items are then sent to form2.cs. on a button click they are placed on my excel template that starts from row 19 and ends at row 49. it is renamed as quote_todays date. I want the balance of the items to go to same template and renamed to quote_todays date page2